# Xaml definition of custom object only works for first instance

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to use xaml to instantiate a set of objects as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:RelationshipDefinition x:Key="R1" Name="College"
        Type="One2one" ForwardName="Attended"
    />

    <local:RelationshipDefinition x:Key="R2" Name="HasPart"
        Type="One2manyBi" ForwardName="Part" BackwardName="PartOf"
    />

    <local:RelationshipDefinition x:Key="R3" Name="HasChild"
        Type="One2manyBi" ForwardName="Child" BackwardName="Parent"
    />
</Application.Resources>
```

The first instance "R1" works, and is instantiated. The other two aren't, even though no errors are thrown. Whichever of the relationships I move into the first place works correctly, so it's clear that it will only "accept" one instance. Is there a way for me to do this? I've experimented with trying to create a Collection class to hold them, but haven't succeeded. Trying to designate the collection as a ContentProperty like this:

```
[ContentProperty("Definitions")]
```

produces this error:

`Error  CS1729  'ContentPropertyAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

I'm new to the ways of xaml, and imagine there must be some fairly easy way to accomplish this.

After my initial post I found that if I created a separate `ResourceDictionary` to hold each `RelationshipDefinition` and included each separately like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="HasChildrenRelationship.xaml"/>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="CollegeRelationship.xaml"/>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="HasPartRelationship.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The `RelationshipDefinition` object is a simple declarative object that is used by a semantic net based data access method. Each user 'declares' the network relationships they well be using in their particular case. Here's a fragment of the code from the class. It's essentially all Dependency Properties with a constructor that registers/finds the `RelationshipDefinition` in a global store.

```
  public class RelationshipDefinition : DependencyObject
  {

    public string UID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NameProperty, value);
            RegisterRelationshipDefinition(this);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(RelationshipDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public RelationshipType Type
    {
        get { return (RelationshipType)GetValue(TypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TypeProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Type", typeof(RelationshipType), typeof(RelationshipDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(null));
...etc...
```

It's used like this:

```
Person chris = new Person(){ FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Smith", Age = 19 };
Person annemarie = new Person() {FirstName = "Anne-Marie", LastName = "Smith", Age = 22 };
Person john = new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", Age = 47};
SNet.Link(from: chris, to: nyu, via: "College");
SNet.Link(from: john, to: chris, via: "HasChild");
SNet.Link(from: john, to: annemarie, via: "HasChild");
Person p1 = SNet.GetBackLink<Person>(from: annemarie, via: "HasChild");
List<Person> children = SNet.GetForwardLinks<Person>(from: john, via: "HasChild");
```

All the `RelationshipDefinition` objects were instantiated correctly. I'm sure there must be a way to include them together that I'm missing.

Comment: Could you show more about `RelationshipDefinition` class and how was it used?

Comment: Nico, I added the information you requested to the original question.

Comment: I could not figure out any relationship between  the Person class and RelationshipDefinition class.

Comment: I don't think this really matters. I'm just trying to instantiate a POCO using XAML, and seem to be limited to one instance per ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Show your xaml that you used.

Comment: But, to answer your question, there is a `RelationshipDefinition` called `HasChild`. 
     `SNet.Link(from: john, to: chris, via: "HasChild");` creates a Relationship from john to chris. Its sematics are defined by the RelationshipDefinition. That is, it is a OneToMany Bidirectional Relationship. The forward link from john to chris is called "Child" and the backward link from chris to john is called "Parent".

Comment: The first lines of the post are XAML Resource definitions. Each one should instantiate a ResourceDefinition object. And they do. But each ResourceDictionary will only allow a single one. In order to instantiate them all, I have to put each one in a single ResourceDictionary all by itself and include all the ResourceDictionaries individually, as I show. I'm trying to figure out how I can include them all in a single dictionary.